# DEM interpolation, QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, dem, interpolation, tin, profile

A friend of mine gave me DEM resolutions of cells 5x5m, but there is something wrong with interpolation. When I try to make a cross-section of the terrain I get a pretty inaccurate cross-section, with weird peaks and valleys. 
What should I do to get a smoother DEM?
These are the extensions:
[image]

[image]

cross-section (There is no waterfall there :-)
[image]

Comment: Honestly, looking at the DEM I see no way to fix this aside from generating it again from the original data with a different method. Ask your friend for better data.

Comment: You think it is not completed or the DEM is damaged? I think that this DEM is generated with some kind of triangulation

Comment: It looks like it is a patchwork of different sources. The bottom of the valley seems derived from hypsometric curves while the hills/mountains around look like a TIN. They transition badly where they meet, and the TIN seems full of artifacts or bad sample points. I hope you're not doing hydrology!

Comment: Not directly with hydrology, but with geomorphometry :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DEM seems to be the result of a Triangulation based on points and lines (probably ArcGis TIN algorithm). One thing that you can do is correct the value of the wrong cells using the Plugin [Serval](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Serval/) that allow you to change "manually" the value of any pixel. In the case of your DEM I think that the amount of the wrong pixels is small and you can try this approach.
I suggest visualising your DEM with Pseudocolour Singleband that exalts the presence of pixel with different values from the surrounding area and, with the Serval tools, just proceed using the *Probing mode* tool to extract the value of a near pixel and copy in the wrong pixel with the *Drawing mode* tool.

Comment: I think there is a lot work to do. There are many mistakes to manually correct.

Comment: I can understand. Another possibility could extract the contours, remove the smallest parts of them with the Simplify algorithm and recreate a DEM from the cleaned contours. But I am not sure of the result without doing some attempts with your DEM.